# Como fazer a relação Pai>Filho entre dois elementos select?

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

estou a fazer dois elementos Select um  "Área" e outro "Problema" e preciso relacionar um com o outro, na tabela do BD do problema esta a FK spr_sar_codigo referente a sar_codigo da tabela Área. não estou conseguindo interagir de forma que o select problema dependa do que for selecionado na área. Aqui estão os dois métodos do Controlador para carregar os dois selects:

```
public function ajaxcarregaarea() {

    $obj_area = new daoArea();
    $areas = $obj_area - > Consultar();
    $select = "<select id='area' name='area' data-obrigatorio='S' class='valido'>";
    $select. = "<option value='' selected='selected'>Selecione a área responsável</option>";
    foreach($areas as $area) {
        $select. = "<option value='".$area['sar_codigo'].
        "'>".$area['sar_titulo'].
        "</option>";
    }
    $select. = "</select>";

    echo $select;
}


public function ajaxcarregaproblema() {

    $obj_problema = new daoProblema();
    $problemas = $obj_problema - > Consultar();
    $select = "<select>";
    $select. = "<option value='' selected='selected'>Selecione a área responsável</option>";
    foreach($problemas as $problema) {
        $select. = "<option value='".$problema['spr_sar_codigo'].
        "'>".$problema['spr_problema'].
        "</option>";
    }
    $select. = "</select>";

    echo $select;
}
```

E aqui esta as divs correspondentes e o que fiz no Script no arquivo onde estão as divs:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-1 cfd">
        <?=$i->getFormularioIdioma("Área Responsável")?>:
    </div>
    <div id="areas" class="col-xs-6 cfb so-awesome1">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-1 cfd">
        <?=$i->getFormularioIdioma("Qual o Problema")?>:
    </div>
    <div id="problemas" class="col-xs-6 cfb so-awesome2">
    </div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.post("<?=$url?>insuporte/abrirchamado/ajaxcarregaarea", {}, function(ajaxcarregaarea) {
        $('#areas').html(ajaxcarregaarea);
    });
});
```

Não sei como fazer para criar essa relação, sei que preciso usar o evento onchange do jquery mas não tive idéia de como fazer, ainda sou iniciante e esytou com muitas dificuldades.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como os problemas dependem diretamente da área, ao carregá-los você vai ter que especificar qual área você selecionou.

A primeira alteração seria na hora de carregar os problemas:

```
public function ajaxcarregaproblema($sar_codigo) {

    $obj_problema = new daoProblema();
    $problemas = $obj_problema - > Consultar($sar_codigo);
    $select = "<select id='slProblema'>";
    $select. = "<option value='' selected='selected'>Selecione a área responsável</option>";
    foreach($problemas as $problema) {
        $select. = "<option value='".$problema['spr_sar_codigo'].
        "'>".$problema['spr_problema'].
        "</option>";
    }
    $select. = "</select>";

    echo $select;
}
```

**Obs1: Estou apenas ilustrando, a alteração terá q ser feita dentro da função "Consultar" da classe "daoProblema"**

A segunda alteração seria justamente o "change" do select de áreas:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.post("<?=$url?>insuporte/abrirchamado/ajaxcarregaarea", {}, function(ajaxcarregaarea) {
        $('#areas').html(ajaxcarregaarea);

        $('#slProblema').change(function(i, e){

            $.post("<?=$url?>insuporte/abrirchamado/ajaxcarregaproblema", {'sar_codigo': $(this).val()}, function(ajaxcarregaproblema) {
                $('#problemas').html(ajaxcarregaproblema);
            });
        });

    });
});
```

Espero ter ajudado, se não totalmente, pelo menos com alguma indicação do caminho. Boa sorte.

Comment: Obrigado verificarei e retorno se deu certo ou não, é mais ou menos assim que trabalhamos aqui onde faço estágio.

Comment: jsanches você ajudou porem não consigo fazer o filtro para aparecer no select problemas somente problemas destinados a area responsavel, poderia me ajudar ainda mais um pouquinho hehe? desculpe

Comment: O filtro que você não está conseguindo fazer é no php ou na consulta ao banco de dados?

Answer (score 2):

Em vez de fazer requisições ajax para cada vez que você muda o select, crie todos eles de um vez, e altera o conteúdo disponível através de uma função.

```js
  function changeChildren(value){
    var select = document.getElementById("childrens");
    select.value = '';  // REMOVE O VALOR ATUAL NO SELECT
    var options = select.getElementsByTagName('option');
    for(var i in options){
      var option = options[i];
      if(typeof option == 'object'){
        if(option.getAttribute('data-father') == value){
          option.style.display = 'block';
        }else{
          option.style.display = 'none';
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

```html
<select id="father" onchange="changeChildren(this.value)">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="1">Father 1</option>
  <option value="2">Father 2</option>
</select>

<select id="childrens">
  <option value="1" data-father="1" style="display:none;">Children 1-1</option>
  <option value="1" data-father="1" style="display:none;">Children 2-1</option>
  <option value="1" data-father="1" style="display:none;">Children 3-1</option>
  <option value="1" data-father="2" style="display:none;">Children 1-2</option>
  <option value="1" data-father="2" style="display:none;">Children 2-2</option>
</select>
```

#### Ponto positivo

- O cliente não realiza requisições ao servidos cada vez que altera o valor no select.
- O conteúdo já esta todo carregado então sera mais rápido apenas exibir os corretos do que renderizá-los.
- Mesmo que o servido caia, continua funcionando, pois ja esta tudo carregado.

#### Ponto negativo

- Se for muitas opções pode deixa o primeiro carregamento da pagina bem lento.

Comment: Muito obrigado, eu entendi mas ainda não me ajudou mas obrigado pelo tempo disponivel.